# Are these symptoms expected when making proxmox ve installable usb?

Tags: proxmox

I'm learning to install proxmox ve but I'm encountering several things that I'm not clear on.

I downloaded proxmox as an iso file from here:
[image]

I bought a new USB stick.  I used Balana Etcher on a Windows 10 to make the USB stick bootable from the ISO.  I tell Etcher to make it D: which is my USB stick on my computer. When Etcher finishes, I see 3 new pop up windows saying the E: drive needs be formatted, F: drive needs to be formatted and G: drive needs to be formatted.  I have no idea why E, F and G drive appears and why they reference they USB stick.  Clicking on E, F or G in windows explorer also gives the same pop up.  The D: drive shows a folder called `efi`.

I can repeat the above scenario with any combination of:

- using a different brand of USB sticks
- replacing Balana Etcher with https://gitlab.com/bztsrc/usbimager
- using a different windows computer

This leads me to believe that what I experienced with the E, F G drives are expected results?

Next, I take one of the USB sticks to a computer that I want to install proxmox too.  I plugin the USB, I turn on the computer, I enter BIO and set Virtualization to Enabled and I change the boot order so that Removeable Device is first.

But when the computer boots up, it goes straight into Windows because Windows is the OS that's been installed on this computer, which I plan to replace with proxmox.  My understanding is that my bootable USB stick should have caused the computer to boot from proxmox instead.  Is that correct?  This situation is the same regardless of which proxmox usb boot stick I use (out of all the ones I made via various permutations of usb stick brand, etching software and windows computer).

Did I do something wrong in the way I'm setting up proxmox?  Are all the symptoms I described above normal?

Comment: A removable device is usually a CD or floppy. USB is almost always labelled as USB. If the drive is not formatted correctly or having the correct layout, the USB stick is not recognised. Also having secure boot on or off will affect things. I always use RUFUS, with FAT32 to be sure I get it to boot.

Comment: Ok I finally got my bios to show USB as a boot option.  Now this seems to be working